# How to COUNTIF two sets of criteria are correct (likely easy)

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Firstly, there are a few (2) threads with /similar/ questions but they have very different criteria and are too complicated to be understood. I apologize if this is a dumb question. Also note: I need this to be a formula, not VBA, if possible. This is because I have to be able to share it with staff who have never used VBA and I need them to have a good understanding of the base functions (such as adjusting ranges, criteria, etc.).

I am trying to use a formula to count cells that meet two sets of criteria.

So essentially, I want a formula that says "if column C is = Closed  and column B = January, count it."

This is similar to "=COUNTIF('Data Sheet'!C:C,"Closed")" but with added criteria.

It is ***essential*** that it meets both sets of criteria and only counts those cases. The correct total for the example would be 3.

Thank you for your help!

[image]

Comment: Use countifs() - which allows you to add as many extra criteria as you wish...

Comment: Have you tried using `=COUNTIFS`? This will allow you to check multiple criteria in multiple ranges.

Comment: Embarrassingly, I did not.. I was busy trying to reinvent the wheel haha.. Thank you both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adjust the ranges, and 'Closed' / 'January' criteria as needed.

```
=COUNTIFS(C1:C4,"Closed",B1:B4,"January")
```

Comment: This is correct. This was an embaressingly easy question haha. Thank you. I will accept this as soon as it allows me. (7 more minutes)

Comment: Thank you - and no worries at all, better to figure it out than spend too long on it!